# How to let the selected cell still selected when I switch the dataSource in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to let the selected cell still selected when I switch the dataSource?

[image]

The gif image shows the current situation.

I do not want that, when I click the switch button, if I choose the "混合", I want the "单" and "双" still selected, and back to "组合玩法", they are also selected.

How to do with that?

---

Attention, when I click the switch button, the dataSource is switched too, but I can use the same dataSource (there is a type to identify the 4 types, they are all contains in the origin dataSource).

The code is below:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (collectionView == self.buy_code_cv) {

        Lucky28BuyCodeCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Lucky28BuyCodeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.model = self.dataSource_code[indexPath.row];

        cell.delegate = self;

        return cell;

    } else {

        Lucky28PlayCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Lucky28PlayCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        if (self.selected_button == 0) {

            cell.model = self.dataSource_method[indexPath.row];
        }else if (self.selected_button == 1) {

            cell.model = self.dataSource_mix[indexPath.row];
        }else if (self.selected_button == 2) {

            cell.model = self.dataSource_color[indexPath.row];
        }else {

            cell.model = self.dataSource_leopard[indexPath.row];
        }

        cell.delegate = self;

        return cell;
    }

}
```

The setSelected method in the cell:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {

    [super setSelected:selected];

    //self.selected = !selected;

    if (selected) {
        self.backView.backgroundColor = APP_COLOR;
        self.number_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.multiple_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
    else {

        self.backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.number_label.textColor = HexRGB(0x999999);
        self.multiple_label.textColor = HexRGB(0xcccccc);
    }

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectedBuyCodeCell:)]) {

        [self.delegate didSelectedBuyCodeCell:self];
    }

}
```

How to do with that?

Comment: Considering your data is saved in four arrays - 
Save your data in array along with selected flag. just reload data on change of tab and if flag==1 change background color of that item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have 4 arrays to save grouped models, the program structure is good enough to have easy solution. (Main idea, not tested in IDE. 提供了实现思路，代码未在IDE中测试，末尾有中文总结)

**First**, add new property in your model for recording selection:

```
@interface YourModel : NSObject
    //...Other properties
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOl selected;
}
```

**Second**, save the selection in collection view delegate methods:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourModel *model;
    if (self.selected_button == 0) {
        model = self.dataSource_method[indexPath.row];
    }else if (self.selected_button == 1) {
        model = self.dataSource_mix[indexPath.row];
    }else if (self.selected_button == 2) {
        model = self.dataSource_color[indexPath.row];
    }else {
        model = self.dataSource_leopard[indexPath.row];
    }

    model.selected = YES;  //key point!
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    YourModel *model;
    if (self.selected_button == 0) {
        model = self.dataSource_method[indexPath.row];
    }else if (self.selected_button == 1) {
        model = self.dataSource_mix[indexPath.row];
    }else if (self.selected_button == 2) {
        model = self.dataSource_color[indexPath.row];
    }else {
        model = self.dataSource_leopard[indexPath.row];
    }

    model.selected = NO; //key point!
}
```

**Third**, restore selection for cell when refreshing the collection view:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
for (int i=0; i<self.dataSource_mix.count; i++) { //The datasource here is only for example, please use the corresponding one. 
    YourModel *model = self.dataSource_mix[i];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    if (model.selected) {
        [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
    else{
        [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

中文总结：

1. model 里提供属性存储是否选中；
2. collection view 的选中和非选中事件中将值保留到model中；
3. 重刷collection view后，将model中的是否选中值反应到cell的界面中。

Comment: Thank you, but in my given code you should know the `dataSource_method `, `dataSource_mix ` and `dataSource_color ` they are different.

Comment: @s-n-2, are they different class of models? So there are 2 ways: 1. Add "selected" property to all models. 2. Make a base model which has "selected" property, then other models inherit from the base one.

Comment: Since you can assign the different models to one kind of cell, that's why I thought there must be some commons in the model.

Comment: Although I will change some thing, but I agree your idea., thanks.

Comment: I don't know why, my selected-cell after reloaded it can not be click now, there is no response.

Comment: @s-n-2, I updated the answer, the third step's behavior is changed. Try it to solve the clicking problem. Remember to remove the "setSelected" code in method "cellForItemAtIndexPath".

Comment: @s-n-2, and remove the "didSelectedBuyCodeCell" calling in cell. That looks also conflicting the click action.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage array of your selected cell. I mean you have to keep track of your selected cell. So, in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` check that if cell is selected (from array or data source or where you keep track of selected state) then show background color and text color of selected state.

you can make cell selected like,

```
 [cell setSelected:YES];
```

And you should modify track record(of selected cell) from `setSelected` method.

Comment: I will try, and by the way, in the UICollectionView's method:`collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, I did not set the cell `[cell setSelected:YES];`, why it is selcted ? it is default in the method?

Comment: I just saying that you can manually make any cell selected like this. If not require than do not call this!

Answer (score 0):

Save the indexpaths before switching the data source.

```
NSArray *indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems;
```

After switching the datasource.

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
        // if you are doing anything with UI on didSelect, you have to call it manually.
        //[self collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]
}
```

Comment: No, when I switch it, the indexPath some where will be change, can not use this to do with that.

Comment: are you maintaining your own selected indexpaths array??